# Leer datos de un archivo

Tags: c#, archivo, bucles

En mi documento de texto tengo los siguientes datos:

- Postgre_Server: 192.168.0.65
- Postgre_Port: 911
- Postgre_Password: unam

Tengo que leerlos y asignarlos a una variable, el código que hice fue este:

```
public static void readData()
    {
        TextReader readFile;
        string chain;
        bool found = false;
        string[] fields = new string[2];
        char[] breakUp = { ':' };
        try
        {

            readFile = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\unam\\Documents\\Hugo\\Datos.txt");


            chain = readFile.ReadLine();



            while (chain != null && found == false)
            {
                fields = chain.Split(breakUp);


                if (fields[0].Trim().Equals("Postgre_Server"))
                {
                    server = fields[1].Trim();

                }else
                    {
                     if(fields[0].Trim().Equals("Postgre_Port"))
                         {
                         port = fields[1].Trim();
                         }else
                             {

                      if(fields[0].Trim().Equals("Postgre_Password"))
                                  {
                                    password = fieldas[1].Trim();
                                  }
                             }
                     }

            } //End While  
readFile.Close();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("¡No se encontró el archivo!" + fe.Message);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("¡No se encontró el archivo!" + e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Pero, al momento de la lectura se queda dentro del primer if, por lo que sólo lee "Postgre_Server" una y otra vez. Mi duda es, ¿cómo puede avanzar a la siguiente línea para que lea el siguiente valor?

Comment: Te falta leer la siguiente linea, cada que leas una linea debes buscar si existe en alguna condicion de tu if, es decir tu comparacion debe estar en otro metodo y ese metodo puede retornar el nombre del campo encontrado port, server, ese campo encontrado lo asignas a tu variable.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día amigo, podés usar la dll System.IO  y luego utilizar la clase StreamReader

```
var file = new StreamReader("la/ruta/de/archivo.txt").ReadToEnd();
//Luego podés convertirlo en una lista para poder iterar más fácil

var listaLineas = file.Split("\n").ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Los datos de conexion a una db son parte de la configuracion de tu aplicacion, no deben estar en un archivo de texto, deben ir en el archivo de confguracion `App.config`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puede definir el connection string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="default" connectionString="Server=192.168.0.65;Port=911Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=unam;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

[PostgreSQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/)

Entonces en tu codigo referencia a

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

define el using

```
using System.Configuration;
```

y lees el valor

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString
```

que entiendo usaras con la libreria `Npgsql`, porque esta es la que usas como provider de ado.net para esta db

[Npgsql nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)